# Gulp is throwing syntax error, probbably compiling dependencies

Tags: gulp

I have the following gulp file:

```
var paths = {
    all: ['*.js', '**/*.js', 'index.html'],
    js: ['*.js', '**/*.js'],
    html: 'index.html',
    dist: 'dist'
};

var gulp = require("gulp");
var babel = require("gulp-babel");

gulp.task("default", function () {
    gulp.src(paths.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
    return gulp.src(paths.js)
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(paths.all, ['default']);
});
```

When I run it, I get this error

```
 SyntaxError: d:/project_folder/node_modules/gulp-babel/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/beeper/index.js: 'return' outside of function (9:1) ...`
```

I read somewhere that I shouldn't compile dependencies. I run just gulp with no following flags. So I don't know wehether or not I do compile them. But gulp seems slow because it takes few seconds to get to first task. How to get rid of this error? And am I doing something wrong with dependencies?

Comment: First thing I'd split your `default` task in two tasks: `compile-html` and `compile-js`. Then I'll make a `default` task that calls them both and start to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are currently including all .js files from the current directory, not the source directories. Your application code (lets assume `app.js`) will "include" your dependencies by using `common js` requires, such as:

```
var request = require('request');
```

In order to actually map the `require` statements you would want to use a module loader, or packer such as: [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) or [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)

The following gulp task will solve the module errors:

```
var paths = {
    all: ['./src**/*.js', 'index.html'],
    js: ['./src/**/*.js'],
    html: 'index.html',
    dist: 'dist'
};

var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
    return gulp.src(paths.js)
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(paths.all, ['default']);
});
```

This only includes all the `.js` files in the `src` folder, not `**/*.js` which will include all `*.js` files in every folder including `node_modules` `bower_components`.

Regarding module loading:

You would probably want to use a loader task to bundle all your client code instead of just copying them to the `dist`, such as:

```
gulp.task("webpack", function(callback) {
    // run webpack
    webpack({
        // configuration
    }, function(err, stats) {
        if(err) throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack", err);
        gutil.log("[webpack]", stats.toString({
            // output options
        }));
        callback();
    });
});
```